# Does my MongoDB need Hadoop?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

My usage of MongoDB is quite simple. I have only a replica set and handle some basic queries without using Map Reduce.

I have heard that Hadoop is great data processing tool which can increase performance once MongoDB connects to. It handle Map Reduce well but is it useful in my case which does not contain any Map Reduce functions?

Moreover, if I use Map Reduce in MongoDB and connect to Hadoop, how will be the performance increased?

Comment: Hadoop solves a completely different set of problems than what you've described. You are handling basic queries - nothing will make that faster except maybe better indexes in MongoDB itself. Hadoop is for off-line batch processing of massively demanding computations.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I am not sure what you mean of off-line batch processing. I have read some notes about Hadoop. It does handle map reduce. Anyways, do u recommend to use Hadoop in my case? Thank you.

Comment: no, your use case doesn't seem to require Hadoop - by definition if it's adequately handled by OLTP system, you don't need a batch system to "help".

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is good for Batch Processing and on a huge volume of data (GB's to TB's).
So if you are not expecting that volume of data in your case and you need instant output of your query you can better do it by mongo alone. Hadoop might be an overkill for the job.

Comment: My MongoDB does have several GB storage so it would have a bit delay for fetching. I am considering to apply Hadoop to improve the latency but I am just not sure whether it is good for my simple queries and the improvement of performance.

Comment: Well you can give it a shot for your own learning, but little latency still does not mean batch mode. Hadoop is for batch jobs which take more time and more volume of data.

Comment: You can also have a look on hive on top of mongodb.